# How to change which Component is listening for events

Tags: java, swing, components, listener

I'm trying to cycle between buttons programmatically, so I need to be able to change which button is listening for events when I move right/left or up/down.

I have tried button.setSelection(true); inherited from AbstractButton but this is clearly not the same thing.

I have looked around and not found much for this dilemma so far, point the way if you could please.

Update: All I really want to do is give a button focus programmatically. All I see are "setFocusable" etc. in the methods; how would I do something like:

Button1.giveFocus();??

Comment: What events do you mean? All buttons listen for action events. Try asking your question as if we have no knowledge of your current program.

Comment: The Component method `requestFocusInWindow()` may do what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is What I was looking fore, thanks. It seems that was sitting in there all along, I suppose it just didn't jump out at me like it should have, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but again, when asking a question here, please assume we are completely ignorant of your project and can't read minds, and it will save you and us a lot of unnecessary comments and time.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you have always add event listener to component and only then get listen to the event :)

If you look at the [mouse listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and its methods as the

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse entered", e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse exited", e);
    }
```

Good luck